# What should be the value of HOST header in a multi layer infrustructure?

Tags: http, networking, http-headers

I'm trying to understand [HOST header](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7230#section-5.4) better. I came up with a question that I was not sure about its correct answer. Suppose I have a couple of nodes (machines/apps) in between my Servlet container and the internet like below:

```
Internet ---> first load balancer ---> a monitoring server/application ---> second load balancer ---> my HTTP Servlet contianer
```

What value should I expect when I call `HttpServletRequest.getHeader("host")`? Should it be host name of "first load balancer" or host name of "second load balancer"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is "it depends". It depends on your HTTP servlet container.

If that is configured to listen to the host "your-public-site.com", just as your first load balancer, and the second load balancer has a pool of IP addresses of servers that can answer requests to "your-public-site.com", the request might just look like this:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: your-public-site.com
```

But connected on IP address. The load balanced servers may as well be called "appsrv01.internal.lan", "appsrv02.internal.lan", and so on, and then *that* is what you'll see.

All of this of course assuming that the second load balancer is configured correctly and knows the host names that the actual servers replying to the requests will respond to.

So: the header you get, is the host name you have configured.

Comment: Based on you answer is it correct to say, If load balanced servers are called by name, like your example (appsrv01.internal.lan, appsrv02.internal.lan), in case my servlet container executes `HttpServletResponse.sendRedirect("/anotherPage.html")` then, the client will receive the address of the internal, second load balancer instead of the first (internet facing) one in the `location` header for redirect. Is this correct?

Comment: That depends on the web framework and load balancer being used, but yes, that's possible. It's also possible that the load balancer translates those links to the external name it's configured with, in response bodies as well as in location headers.